# Get element's text by TabIndex in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

How to get element's text by TabIndex in Windows Forms?
smth like:

```
"this.Controls.GetElementByTabindex(1).text"
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `LINQ`:

```
var text = this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
               .Where(c => c.TabIndex == index)
               .Select(c => c.Text)
               .First();
```

If you want to do it with extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetElementTextByTabIndex(this Control.ControlCollection controls,int index)
    {
        return controls.OfType<Control>()
                       .Where(c => c.TabIndex == index)
                       .Select(c => c.Text).First();
    }
}

string text = this.Controls.GetElementTextByTabIndex(1);
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really strange but I didn't find the answer in the Internet)

Comment: @DiA

how would you go about specifying it to start at the 13th tab index textbox location and end at the 33rd tab index with LINQ?

Comment: totally unrelated sort of but I want to get the text starting at the 13th tab index textbox and end at the 33rd (last textbox).

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use linq, this can do this:

```
int index = 1;    
string text;

foreach(Control control in Controls)
{
    if(control.TabIndex == index)
    {
        text = control.Text;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
   string tabText= tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text;
   MessageBox.Show(tabText);
```